# Cocos2d V3.4 Chipmunk RELEASE mode display bug

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

there seems to be a Cocos2dV3.4 display bug when adding lots of  Chipmunk physics bodies quickly in the same spot in RELEASE MODE on a device. If the physics body is a rectangle its happens straight away, if it is a circle it takes longer but does happen. The key point is it always works fine in DEBUG mode but errors occur in RELEASE mode on the device. It always works fine in the simulator. (just Edit Scheme.. to change to release mode for RUN)

Example swift code to replicate. (simply add a dynamic polygon physics body at the same point quickly)

```
class MainTestScene: CCNode
{
    var _rootPhysicsNode : CCPhysicsNode!
    var count : CCTime = 0

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        _rootPhysicsNode = CCPhysicsNode()
        _rootPhysicsNode.gravity = ccp(0,-100)
        self.addChild(_rootPhysicsNode)
    }

    override func update(delta: CCTime)
    {
        count += delta
        if count > 0.2
        {
            count = 0
            for var i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++
            {
                let item = CCSprite(imageNamed: "ccbResources/rainbowblinky.png")
                item.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5)
                item.scale = 0.3
                item.position = ccp(CCDirector.sharedDirector().viewSize().width / 2,  CCDirector.sharedDirector().viewSize().height / 2 )
                item.physicsBody = CCPhysicsBody(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), cornerRadius: 1)
                _rootPhysicsNode.addChild(item)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In DEBUG mode you get sprites falling from a point and pushing each other out. (see picture) In RELEASE MODE on an iOS device the screen flicks every second shows a single sprite and slows down to a crawl.

[image: DEBUG mode works]

Can someone help? Am I doing something wrong?
B

Comment: update: it seems to relate to swift optimisation bug. If you use comiler switch -O1 to turn off optimisations its works.

Comment: FIX: Simply add "-fno-fast-math" to the "cpCollision.c" file in the Build Phases of the Chipmunk library which turns off optimizations only on this one file.